# Appending JSONObject to JSONArray of JSON file residing in res/raw folder

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to append JSONObject to JSONArray of JSON file residing in res/raw folder but while doing so getting i'm getting IllegalArgumentException as seen in the logcat below:

Please Guide Me.
Thanks in Advance

```
03-23 13:38:36.219 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File android.resource://in.naushad.cctexample/2131099648 contains a path separator
03-23 13:38:36.229 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:2457)
03-23 13:38:36.229 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileOutput(ContextImpl.java:999)
03-23 13:38:36.229 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:188)
03-23 13:38:36.229 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at in.naushad.cctexample.add_entry.AppendContentsToJSON(add_entry.java:88)
03-23 13:38:36.229 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at in.naushad.cctexample.add_entry.access$000(add_entry.java:20)
03-23 13:38:36.229 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at in.naushad.cctexample.add_entry$1.onClick(add_entry.java:38)
03-23 13:38:36.230 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4797)
03-23 13:38:36.230 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19899)
03-23 13:38:36.230 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-23 13:38:36.230 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-23 13:38:36.230 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-23 13:38:36.230 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310)
03-23 13:38:36.230 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-23 13:38:36.230 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-23 13:38:36.230 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
03-23 13:38:36.230 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
03-23 13:38:36.230 2180-2180/in.naushad.cctexample W/System.err:     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:117)
```

add_entry activity:

```
package in.naushad.cctexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class add_entry extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etAddLen,etAddDen,etAddPersonName;
    Button btAddEntry;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_entry);

        initXML();

        btAddEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String StringetAddLen=etAddLen.getText().toString();
                String StringetAddDen=etAddDen.getText().toString();
                String StringetAddPersonName=etAddPersonName.getText().toString();

                AppendContentsToJSON(StringetAddLen,StringetAddDen,StringetAddPersonName);

                startActivity(new Intent(add_entry.this,MainActivity.class));
            }
        });


    }

    void initXML(){
        etAddLen = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddLen);
        etAddDen = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddDen);
        etAddPersonName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddPersonName);
        btAddEntry = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAddEntry);

    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }

    private void AppendContentsToJSON(String StringetAddLen1,String StringetAddDen1,String StringetAddPersonName1)
    {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
            JSONObject jO = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray jArry = jsonObjMain.getJSONArray("JSONLenDen");

            //Add Data
            jO.put("Len", StringetAddLen1);
            jO.put("Den",StringetAddDen1);
            jO.put("Name",StringetAddPersonName1);

            //Append
            jArry.put(jO);

            try {
                String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.data;
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(path, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String test=jsonObjMain.toString();
                fos.write(test.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(add_entry.this,"exception",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

data.json in res/raw:

```
  {
  "JSONLenDen": [
    {
      "Len": "125",
      "Den": "685",
      "Name":"A"
    },
    {
      "Len": "385",
      "Den": "3248",
      "Name":"B"
    },
    {
      "Len": "385",
      "Den": "3248",
      "Name":"C"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to write to the resources at runtime? I may be wrong, but it looks like you are. And resources are read-only at runtime and cannot be written to... you can write only to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Yes,i was trying just that.So according to you i should store the JSON file in the phone's internal storage,if i'm not mistaken. Can you give me an idea or least point me to a relevant thread which explains loading the json data and doing operations such as appending,editing data in it ,while it exists in the phones internal storage?

Comment: edit: [Solved] Thanks for your info , really helped to solve the problem.it's working now as i create json file at runtime placed in the phone's internal storage. Wish i could upvote the comment but i guess i cant.

Comment: @varren I suggest making your comment an answer :)